# _com_util::ConvertStringToBSTR - Access Violation

Tags: c++, string, com, access-violation, bstr

I'm invoke COM server's method and randomly get access violation error in the _com_util::ConvertStringToBSTR:

```
g_quote->RegisterQuote(_bstr_t(pszTicker), _bstr_t(_T("*")));
```

RegisterQuote signature:

```
HRESULT __stdcall RegisterQuote(BSTR bstrSymbol, BSTR bstrExch);
```

More information:

```
int GetQuotesEx(LPCTSTR pszTicker, int nPeriodicity, int nLastValid, int nSize, struct Quotation* pQuotes, GQEContext* pContext) {
    const RecentInfoMap::const_iterator it = g_mapRecentInfo.find(pszTicker);
    if (it == g_mapRecentInfo.end()) {
        g_quote->RegisterQuote(_bstr_t(pszTicker), _bstr_t("*"));
        return nLastValid + 1;
    }
}
```

I don't know why this bug happens. I can provide additional info if needed.

UPDATE:

[image]

[image]

Comment: In case of access violation your additional info is call stack at exception point.

Comment: I was made screenshots of error messages with callstack.

Comment: What it more looks like, is that your argument itself (`pszTicker`?) is not a valid zero terminated string and causes the problem.

Comment: I found that the problem is not with pszTicker. Probably this exceptions occurs when using _bstr_t in another method.

Comment: I fixed this issue. Problem was with passing NULL BSTR string to _bstr_t constructor.